# struts-layout multiple submit buttons using reqCode

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts

I am using struts-layout on my JSP page to display a table with radio buttons. It has a submit button that calls an execute method in a struts action class. This is working fine.

I need to add another submit button to the same form to either execute another method or somehow simply realize that the second button is clicked in the same method of action class. I understand that this can be done using reqCode. But I just cant figure out how.

My JSP Code:

```
 <layout:form action="/taskSelected.do" reqCode="execute" >
    <layout:submit value="Show Task Status" styleClass="btn btn-default"/>
    <layout:submit value="troubleshoot" styleClass="btn btn-default" reqCode="troubleshoot"/>
    <layout:collection name="userTasks" title="" styleClass="FORM" selectProperty="uniqueID" selectType="radio">
    <layout:collectionItem title="Task Name" property="name"/>
    <layout:collectionItem title="UID" property="uniqueID" />
    <layout:collectionItem title="Request Time" property="add_info" />
    <layout:collectionItem title="FTP URL" property="ftp_url"/>
    <layout:collectionItem title="Status" property="status" />
    </layout:collection>
```

My struts-config.xml

```
 <action name="taskBean" path="/taskSelected" scope="session" type="com.myapp.struts.taskSelectedAction" validate="false">
        <forward name="success" path="/ShowTaskStatus.jsp"/>
        <forward name="troubleshootPage" path="/ShowTroubleshoot.jsp"/>
        <forward name="failure" path="/ViewTasks.jsp"/>
    </action>
```

My Action Class first method:

```
public ActionForward troubleshoot(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Method 1= " + request.getSession().getAttribute("troubleshoot"));

    if(request.getSession().getAttribute("USER_KEY")==null){
        return mapping.findForward("NotLoggedIn");
    }
    System.out.println("Reached in Troubleshoot");
    return mapping.findForward("troubleshootPage");

}
```

Second Method

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Method 2= " + request.getSession().getAttribute("troubleshoot"));
    if(request.getSession().getAttribute("USER_KEY")==null){
        return mapping.findForward("NotLoggedIn");
    }
```

This is supposed to be very simple, but I just cant figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use two buttons instead in your JSP page (I also tried two submits at one point but didn't work for me).

```
<input type="button" value="Method1" onclick="location.href='taskSelected.do?method=method1';"/>
<input type="button" value="Method2" onclick="location.href='taskSelected.do?method=method2';"/>
```

In your struts-config.xml file, add parameter= method

```
<action name="taskBean"
        path="/taskSelected" 
        scope="session" 
        type="com.myapp.struts.taskSelectedAction" validate="false"
        parameter=method>
```

You will only need a single action class.

```
public class taskSelectedAction extends org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction{

    public ActionForward method1(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception{
       //your code goes here     
    }

    public ActionForward method2(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception{
       //your code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. With this approach at least I can get the two different buttons to call two separate methods. But what about the data in the DataGrid? I have a Layout collection(Datagrid) and my goal is to identify which row in the grid user has selected. Based on the row he selected and button he presses I need to initiate separate tasks. With this approach the select property (which is uniqueID in this case) returns null.

Comment: You will need to create a FormBean and make getter/setter methods for the form properties in it.